# Jupyter Deep Learning AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble setting up Jupyter Notebook in my EC2 Instance (Deep Learning AMI Linux). I followed the tutorial from this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-deep-learning-work-station-in-aws-ac99101bf5de). Imanaged to finish all without any problems except launching the notebook. In the SSH terminal, after I inputed the `jupyter notebook` command, it says my notebook is running in `https://ip-172-*-*-*:8888/`, but when I opened that link, it just says **the site can't be reached**. Same problem when I inputed my instance's public DNS with `:8888` at the end.

Can someone tell my what I might be doing wrong?

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/setup-jupyter.html is the official document to setup the Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havae found the solution, it turns out the links didn't specify that the EC2 instance has to allow HTTPS connection. So, I added a `Custom TCP Rule`, with prot range `443`, and Souce `0.0.0.0/0` to the security group.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the following procedure:

1. `jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser`
2. Access jupyter notebook index from your web-browser by visiting:

`<IPv4 public IP address displayed on EC2 Dashboard> :8888/?token=...`

Hope this helps.